# Ember.View - How to append another Ember.View to a jQuery HTML element the right way?

Tags: ember.js

Within `Ember.View` is it possible to do something like this:

```
App.ExperimentalView = Ember.View.extend({
  templateName: 'experimental/table',

  click: function (event) {
    var $target = $(event.target).closest('tr'),
        anotherView = Ember.View.create({
          templateName: 'experimental/appendableRow'
        };

    anotherView.appendTo($target);
  }
});
```

to add a `<tr/>` which has it's HTML markup defined within a `Handlebars` template only if the element is clicked?

First I thought of using an `Ember.ContainerView` but then I reread the docs and stumbled upon this sentence:

> The HTML contents of a Ember.ContainerView's DOM representation will
>   only be the rendered HTML of its child views.

which lead me to the assumption that I would need an `Ember.ContainerView` representing my table whith a child view to hold the real `<table/>` which again has child views and also another `Ember.ContainerView` object which would represent my table body without actually rendering a `<tbody/>` element which seems a bit odd imho.

### EDIT

Another benefit of this approach would probably be that you'll be able to declare a `Ember.Mixin` which provides not only methods/properties but also its own `Handlebars` template. So it would be possible to, let's say, create something like a `FilterableViewMixin` with the HTML markup for the filter and everything and you just would have to implement and reset the filter entries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd do it slightly differently. In the template `experimental/table` add the snippet contained in `experimental/appendableRow` and wrap it in an if statement. Then if the user clicks on the table row, the view can delegate the click to the controller, which will toggle the condition, and thereby display the `experimental/appendableRow` snippet.

Comment: thanks for your reply! this seems pretty good to me, except when I create my `<tr/>` elements in a `{{each}}` and want the appendable row to be injected below the clicked element. so that I have `<tr class="permantent"></tr><tr class="injected"></tr>`. the reason why I want to do it like this is that it would save from rendering the same `<tr/>` element over and over again...

Comment: If you can create jsbin or a fiddle, it could be helpful. I think I understand what you're trying to do, but you needn't have extra unused `<tr/>`. You'll probably have to nest a view, like you mentioned, though shouldn't have to manually create them on click.

Comment: I put together a gruesome example (not fully functional) of your advice over at jsbin (http://jsbin.com/uyolig/1/edit) and I was surprised that this works like I want it to work! thanks a lot! (one last question: could you please checkout my jsbin and tell me what I'm doing wrong?)

Comment: [Here's the jsbin](http://jsbin.com/ixugup/2/edit). Its a little hack, since one shouldn't update model fields for display, but you'll get the idea.